# jQuery plugin for pop up message after form submission

Tags: jquery, popup, form-submit

Does anyone know any jquery plugin to show successful pop up message after form submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a [dialog option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and a lot of other stuff as well.

Comment: Is there a way if I can stop that dialog box for few seconds before form gets submitted.? What I mean is , user presses the submit button, dialog box is notification for user and that dialog box should be constant there for couple of seconds before the form is submitted.

Comment: Yes, when the user submits the form, it is most likely a hyperlink / button of some sort. In your javascript event handler for the hyperlink, return false (that will prevent the default behavior of redirecting the user). You can use a number of functions to wait for x seconds before you then redirect the user. You can use the callback functions for example (where you can set the wait).

Comment: I need to make that dialog box to wait. There is no option for that. Do you know any other function in jquery for that?